# Hexa base digit and Decimal base digit at C#

Tags: c#, hex

Some of my downloaded c# code include hexadecimal based calculation.

```
eg. int length = ((((byte) hexstr[0x10]) & 0x80) > 0) ? 0x10 : 8;
```

when i change this code to normal decimal based code like that

```
int length = ((((byte) hexstr[16]) & 128) > 0) ? 16 : 8;
```

It give the same solution without giving any error.
It still run correctly.
So what I would like to know is why most of the code use hexadecimal base digit which is more difficult to understand than normal decimal digit.

If there anyone who know this, please let me know it.

Comment: The only one who can answer this is the author of the code. It seems that since the logic is Hex related, it can make sence to use the hex notation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows the bit pattern more clearly. 0x80 is clearly the value with the top nybble set to 8 and the bottom nybble set to 0... that's not at all clear from the decimal value.

As another example, if I wanted to mask the second and third bytes of an integer, I might use:

```
int masked = original & 0xffff00;
```

I wrote that code without a calculator or anything similar. There's no way I'd have done the same for the decimal equivalent - I can't multiply 65535 by 256 in my head with any likelihood of success, and the resulting code wouldn't have been nearly as clear anyway.

Comment: Aaah ... i am slow yet again  +1

Comment: As I am beginner to hexa digit at C# field, 
I don't understand what you mean about 
"if I wanted to mask the second and third bytes of an integer".
Could you please explain me more about that ?

Comment: @MyatThu: It's not really do to with C# at all - it's simply the binary representation of integers. "Masking" refers to effectively removing some bits and retaining others - so my mask here preserved the middle 16 bits of a 32 bit integer, and clears the remainder. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)